# Where is the Javascript console (like in Chrome) in Safari 6?

Tags: macos, safari, developer-tools

I'm a heavy Chrome user for development, and wanted to try out Safari, but how do I get the console to see my traces and other outputs?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Web Inspector pane open and focused, click on the "speech bubble" icon above the left-hand pane, or press Control-8.

Update: Or, whether the Web Inspector pane is open or not, press Option-Command-C; or, if you have made the Developer menu visible in Safari's preferences, drop down "Develop" and choose "Show Error Console".

Comment: thanks! :D Sorry for the delayed check, I thought I had come back. I noticed that I couldn't see the chat bubble when the inspector was in attached mode. I could see it when it was in 'detached' mode.

Comment: The menu option is now called "Show JavaScript Console" (Safari 12.0)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are fine, but for prosperity (Google search completeness...): on Mac OSX you open Chrome developer tools with Option+Cmd+I (or Option+Cmd+J to go directly to the JavaScript Console). With *Safari* it is Option+Cmd+C.

**To enable the Developer Tools in Safari:**

1. Open Safari Preferences - Cmd+,
2. Advanced tab
3. At the bottom of the dialog, click the "Show Develop menu in menu bar"
4. Close the dialog - Cmd+w
5. Now Safari shows the Develop menu
6. The Develop menu has the option "Show Error Console - Option+Cmd+C"

Press Option+Cmd+C to open the developer tools window, similar to Chrome's...

For me, the Safari JavaScript console seems to be a bit better than Chrome on a Mac for debugging AngularJS module loading errors :-)

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's [Using the Console to Debug JavaScript in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH8-SW17):

> You can also press the Esc key anywhere in Web Inspector to move focus to the Quick Console in the bottom bar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I had closed it and can't find any other way to re-open it except by hitting esc

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Safari 9x:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Step 2:**

Now on right click on the page, it will give the option to inspect.

[[image][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9nyk.png)]

[[image]]

Mother yaker, Bukklau sala Safari.